# Angular:Argument of type 'Observable<Order[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Order[]>[]'

Tags: angular

I am trying to use mat-paginator, where I need to assign the data from firebase-collection to `MatTableDataSource`.
here is what I am trying to do:

```
private orderCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Order>;
public bookings: Observable<Order[]>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;  
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Observable<Order[]>>;
```

in Constructor:

```
this.orderCollection = this.afs.collection<Order>('bookings');
this.bookings = this.orderCollection.valueChanges();
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.bookings);
```

now I am getting compilation error like:

```
(property) OrderListComponent.bookings: Observable<Order[]>
Argument of type 'Observable<Order[]>' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'Observable<Order[]>[]'.
Type 'Observable<Order[]>' is missing the
following properties from type 'Observable<Order[]>[]': length, pop,
> push, concat, and 28 more.
```

note:if I define `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<<Order[]>;`
the result is simply `Order[]`

but if I define `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Observable<Order[]>>;`
this appends an `[]` in the end;
like- 'Observable<Order[]>[]'

so If there is a way to define observable which will not append `[]`

then I believe this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

change `public bookings: Observable<Order[]>;` to `public bookings: Observable<Order[]>[];` and try.

Comment: I already tried that that, but getting another error like:1st I was getting error shown in question on assigning to `this.dataSource`, but If I change as per your suggestion, I get error on assigning `this.order`. error shown is like this:`Type 'Observable<Order[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Order[]>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more`